# Is there a way to add a response header containing proxied server name on nginx?

Tags: nginx

We are trying to figure out how to add the chosen server in response headers.

For now, we use **$upstream_addr** to get **ip address and port**, and it works, but is there a way to get server hostname instead of ? (just as declared in 'upstream' block)

Here is our (simplified) nginx configuration :

```
upstream my_upstream  {
    ip_hash;
    server production001 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=15s;
    server production002 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=15s;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass      http://my_upstream  ;
        add_header X-Upstream $upstream_addr always;
    }
}
```

Which produces the following header in response : "x-upstream: XX.XX.XX.XX:XXXX"

What we would like to get : "x-upstream: production001"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the IP address of the upstream servers then you could use a map

```
  upstream my_upstream {
    ip_hash;
    server prod1:80;
    server prod2:80;
    server prod3:80;
  }

  map $upstream_addr $upstream_name {
    ~.*192.168.1.1:80   production1;
    ~.*192.168.1.2:80   production2;
    ~.*192.168.1.3:80   production3;
    default             $upstream_addr;
  }

  server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass      http://my_upstream  ;
        add_header X-Upstream $upstream_name always;
    }
}
```

You need the regex in the map for when NGINX tries more than one server, the last name in the list is the server that responded.